# Solving $U_{xy} = 2xyU_{y}$ with $U(1,y) = e^y + 1$, $U(x,0) = 1/x^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a PDE

> $$U_{xy} = 2xyU_{y}$$
>   with $U(1,y) = e^y + 1$ and $U(x,0) = 1/x^2$.

My attempt to solve is as follows:

Let $V(x,y) = U_y(x,y)$. Note that
\begin{align}
    U(1,y) &= e^y + 1\\
    U_y(1,y) &= e^y\\
    V(1,y) &= e^y
\end{align}

Substituting,
\begin{align}
\renewcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}
    V_x(x,y) &= 2xyV(x,y)\\
    \int_{V(1,y)}^{V(x,y)}\frac{\d V}{V} &= \int_{1}^{x}2xy \d x\\
    \ln V - \ln e^y &= x^2y - 1^2y\\
    V &= e^{x^2y}\\
    U_y &= e^{x^2y}\\
    \int_{0}^{y}U_y \d y &= \int_0^y e^{x^2y} \d y\\
    U(x,y) - U(x,0) &= \dfrac{e^{x^2y}}{x^2} - \dfrac{e^{0}}{x^2}\\
    U(x,y) &= \dfrac{e^{x^2y}}{x^2} - \dfrac{1}{x^2} + \dfrac{1}{x^2}\\
    U(x,y) &= \dfrac{e^{x^2y}}{x^2}
\end{align}

However, despite satisfying the PDE. My answer gives wrong initial condition along $x=1$ (should be $e^y + 1$ but I got $e^y$). I couldn't quite figure out where I make the mistake.

Comment: Is it possible there is a typo in your question? The boundary conditions don't agree in the point $(1,0)$. If you substitute $y=0$ in the first condition, you get $U(1,0)  = e^0 + 1 = 2$, but if you substitute $x=1$ in the other one, one gets $U(1,0)=\frac{1}{1^2}=1$. What is the domain you want to solve this equation on?

Comment: @Ernie060 I'm suspecting that too. The domain is not stated in the question so I supposed it's $\mathbb{R}^2$. I tried solving by doing indefinite integration and found inconsistencies at $(1,0)$ as well. Perhaps there might be a mistake in the question itself after all :/